# Laravellocalization search in different language

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to search in different language.
How i read in documentation i must use ' join ' on translations but it don't working.

Every search works except translations.

Controller:

```
public function webSearch(Request $request)
    {
        $translations = \DB::table('articles')->join('translations')->where('value', 'LIKE', "%{$request->search}%")->orderBy('published_at', 'Desc')->get();
        $articles = Article::where('title', 'LIKE', "%{$request->search}%")->orderBy('published_at', 'Desc')->get();
        $episodes = Episode::where('title', 'LIKE', "%{$request->search}%")->orderBy('published_at', 'Desc')->get();
        $quizzes = Quizze::where('title', 'LIKE', "%{$request->search}%")->orderBy('published_at', 'Desc')->get();
        $shows = Show::where('title', 'LIKE', "%{$request->search}%")->orderBy('published_at', 'Desc')->get();
        return view('pages/search')
            ->with('articles', $articles)
            ->with('episodes', $episodes)
            ->with('quizzes', $quizzes)
            ->with('shows', $shows)
            ->with('translations', $translations);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

[Join](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#joins) should be used Like this:

The first argument passed to the join method is the name of the table you need to join to, while the remaining arguments specify the column constraints for the join.

```
$translations = \DB::table('articles')
->join('translations','articles.id','=','translations.article_id')
->where('value', 'LIKE', "%{$request->search}%")->orderBy('published_at', 'Desc')->get();
```

Comment: Hello that's not working i did $translations = Article::join('translations', 'articles.id', '=', 'translations.id') 
        ->where('value', 'LIKE', "%{$request->search}%")->orderBy('published_at', 'Desc')->get();   but it's searching wrong articles